# email input are not saved(cached) by browser with angular.js Form

Tags: html, forms, angularjs

I am having some trouble getting any browser to "remember" the entered email inputs in my login form.
for some reason, after opening the login form again, the old attempts will not be shown.
other inputs (from other sites) does show.

I have searched on many posts and it seems my form is ok. 
I would appreciate some help here.

this is my code:

```
<form ng-submit="login(loginForm)" name="loginForm" class="form-horizontal">
  <div ng-show="showLoginFields" class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">username</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input name="email" type="email" ng-model="login.username">         
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="showLoginFields" class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">password</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="password" ng-model="login.password">
    </div>
  </div>

  <input ng-disabled="disableButtons" type="submit"/>

</form>
```

thanks.

Comment: Is there an `ng-if`, `ng-switch` or `ng-include` above the form such that the form may not exist on the page on the first load?

Comment: no. but it is inside a bootstrap modal.

Comment: Is it present in the DOM (possibly with `display: none` or `left: -9999px` to hide it) when the page is first loaded by Chrome? If it is being added to the DOM _after_ the page load, browsers may not recognize it as a auto-savable-input-box.

Comment: it may be that it is not present when the page loads because the login opens only after a user click the login option. i guess it then creates the element. i tried to look inside the bootstrap css but it is a bit to much for me. how would one solve this issue if this is actually the problem?

Comment: You can check it by loading the page and then doing a `$('[name=email]')` search in the console and seeing whether there is a DOM element already in or not (without clicking the `login` button, of course). The solution is to have it in the DOM when the page loads and showing the modal dialog some way which just makes it visible/invisible rather than removes/add it to the DOM.

Comment: ok. so it is not in the dom whilst the log in modal is not open.
isn't there a basic solution maybe? i am not going to change the bootstrap css and javascript files...

Comment: Question: When the page is loaded, does $scope.login.username have a value that is received from the server? As in when someone loads the page, if they have an account with an email, then it will pre-populate when they arrive.